# Is it possible to use Azure Data Factory on-premise without data running through the cloud?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

is it possible to use Azure Data Factory on-premise without letting the data run through the cloud? I know Talend got a prodcut, where the data is transfered only on our machines and not in the cloud.

Read documentation on Microsoft.com but didnt find any useful information

Answer (score 1):

You may use a self-hosted integration runtime to transfer data entirely through your on-premises infrastructure, as long as both the data source and sink are on-premises.

However, the control flow will still happen through the cloud, even if the data itself never leaves your data center. For this reason, setting up a self-hosted integration runtime will still require outbound network access from your infrastructure to Azure.

Check out this piece of documentation for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#command-flow-and-data-flow